# Why the array doesn't take the values of previous instructions but only the last?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Driver {
    
   static int array[] = {0,0,0,0,0};  

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++ ) {
            array[i] = 5;
            array[i] = 4;
            array[i] = 10;
            array[i++] = 2;
            
        }
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

}
```

result : [2,0,2,0,2]

I was thinking that only the last one ( [i++] ) is take into account and ignore the previous values

Comment: *I was thinking that only the last one ( [i++] ) is take into account* - you thought correct, then. Note; the code contains two `i++` ... what effect do you think it will have?

Comment: You assign to the same entry 4 times.

Comment: @khelwood I think ADL92 knows it, judging by the *"ignore the previous values"* comment...

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore the previous values"? What do you expect the output to be?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why the array doesn't take the values of previous instructions but only the last?

```
// hope you are talking about this part,
array[i] = 5;
array[i] = 4;
array[i] = 10;
array[i++] = 2;
```

This is how the language is designed. You are effectively assigning a value to a same variable (array[i] is pointing to a memory location and you are assigning values for that location in all four lines). So as expected the last one will be the one who remains in that location, which is `2`.

*And to explain the behavior of your code,*

You have two places where you increment the value of `i` in the same iteration in the loop. So effectively you are looking at every other element in the `array`

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; /* no need this  part */ ) {
        array[i] = 5;
        array[i] = 4;
        array[i] = 10;
        array[i++] = 2; // this line will increase the value of `i`
        
    }
```

Comment: you should really increment the index in the `for` line to keep the code readable, and make it obvious there is some dead code that should be eliminated.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet well I was pointing out the behavior of the posted code. And why the code is not giving the expected result. You can make the code readable later, and those array assignments given in the code is something he put there to try/experiment something.

Answer (score 1):

Does it help if I point out that your code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++ ) {
        array[i] = 5;
        array[i] = 4;
        array[i] = 10;
        array[i++] = 2;
        
    }
```

Is the same as this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i+=2 ) {
        array[i] = 2;
    }
```

Same result; redundancies removed